# Quotient group and epimorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I wonder if the statement below is right:
"If there is an epimorphism from $G$ to $H$, we can say that $H$ is a quotient group of $G$."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! this is the first [isomorphism Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems).

> Theorem: Let $H,K$ be two groups and $\varphi:H\rightarrow K$ be a homomorphism. Then, $$H/\ker\varphi \cong Im\varphi$$

In particular when $\varphi$ is onto you have that $K$ is (isomorphic to) a quotient.

Comment: It should be noted that if by "epimorphism" we mean the categorical notion (i.e. $v\circ f=u\circ f\Rightarrow u=v$ for all $u,v$), then it is not trivial that every epimorphism in the category of groups is surjective (and it is false in the categories of monoids or rings).